# Do we have any example or sample code to use proxy pallet?

Tags: pallet, proxy

I want to use the proxy pallet in my code. Do we have any sample Substrate example code to use it?

Comment: Please update your question to represent a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For example, what language are you programming in, what are you trying to do, what have you tried, what errors are you seeing, etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I integrated the proxy pallet into my code [here](https://github.com/DataHighway-DHX/node/pull/213/files) mid last year. It is a sample of the Substrate code you might need to use it if you were still using an earlier version of Substrate version 3.0.0.

To integrate the proxy pallet from the latest Substrate 'master' branch you can refer to files like [bin/node/runtime/src/lib.rs](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/bin/node/runtime/src/lib.rs#L315) that show how to incorporate it into your runtime.

There is example Substrate code in the unit test file of the proxy pallet that shows different scenarios of how you may use the proxy pallet.

For example it shows [in this unit test](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/proxy/src/tests.rs#L207) how to use its `add_proxy` extrinsic. For the latest 'master' branch [it is implemented here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/proxy/src/lib.rs#L234) and [documented here](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/pallet_proxy/pallet/struct.Pallet.html#method.add_proxy).

Comment: Why would one require the use of pallet-proxy?

Comment: the DataHighway project used the 'membership' frame from Substrate to create a whitelist of Supernode `AccountId`s that were granted proxy permission to claim DHX Mining rewards on behalf of their members that were eligible for them.